# django verify HttpResponse reached user

Tags: python, django, http

Is there anyway to make sure that an HttpResponse in django has successfully reached the end-user?

A normal TCP connection will end with FIN request! Could this be detected?

Currently, I save data in a temporary table and once the device receives the data, it sends a "confirmation message" to the server which in turn pulls data from temporary table and commits it.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is no.  In production, there will be several layers of abstraction on top of django that prevent django from getting the level of detail that you want.  In a small production set up, you will have

```
user --> nginx or apache --> gunicorn or wsgi running django
```

So at best, django will only be able to tell if nginx or apache received the response.

In larger scale production systems you will have

```
user --> load balancer --> nginx or apache --> gunicorn or wsgi running django
```

And in some even larger production scale systems you might see:

```
user --> cloudflare or incapsula (caching and firewall service) --> load balancer --> nginx or apache --> gunicorn or wsgi running django
```

So the short answer is, absent a special ACK or confirmation message, like the one that you already have in place, this can’t be done.